# how to diagnose a remote mysql database connection?

Tags: mysql

Our company hosts our server off site through another company who provides web hosting.

I ftp and plesk control panel as means of accessing. Plesk control panel has phpMyAdmin installed so that I can interface with the database "directly".

I've download MySQL query browser and I've been attempting to connect to the database server using that with no luck.

I recieve a MySQL Error Number 2003 when trying to connnect using MySQL query builder. I've read that error code could mean anything from a wrong port to username and password.

Is there a better way to diagnose why I can't connect?

Comment: Have you verified with your hosting company that they allow the incoming MySQL connections through their firewall?  This is most likely the issue.

Comment: When I ping the server with the MySQL query browser I get responses. Does that mean that It's not blocked by a firewall?

Comment: Not necessarily, they may have the firewall allowing pings through, but still blocking port 3306.  You need to ask them if they allow connections on port 3306 (that's the MySQL port).

Comment: Is it possible to ping that specific port?

Comment: You really should be discussing this with your hosting provider.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Error 2003 indicates that the connection has been refused. This could be because a firewall blocks it, or because the mysql server is configured only to allow unix socket connections which can only be local, or only local ip connections via the 127.0.0.1 interface.

You need to examine the mysql configuration file in /etc to see how it is configured if you have the access rights for it. Otherwise you probably will not be able to change it anyway, since you might need to change this file if it is configured in this way.

However, you should be very careful if you allow remote connections, since they could also be a security problem.

Comment: It turns out that the server providers blocks (firewall) the required connections to interface directly with the database.

Answer (score 1):

Most hosting company does not allow remote connections due to security reason, you may ask them thru their support if they allow remote connection to your database. I am also looking for hosting that will allow remote database connection. Hope it may help.

Kenneth